# Colinearity between treatment and independent variable

Tags: interaction, multicollinearity

When you are studying a moderation effect of a factor, say license choice `z` (that has two treatments - choosing an open license `1` or not `0`), on the relationship between an independent variable `x` and outcome variable `y`. Is it expected that `x` and `z` are non-correlated.

Does the presence of collinearity between `x` and `z` raise concerns of endogeneity and prevent us from drawing conclusion for the interaction effect? If yes, is there any robustness test that can be used to improve the confidence in the model and results ?

I have tried my sincere best to answer this question and I have reached out since I have pretty much reached a dead-end. I appreciate any feedback and help.Thank you.

Comment: Why do you call gender a treatment rather then a factor?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I am sorry about that. I have not given a close enough example. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. As an example, say age is one of your dependents and this license factor is the treatment. Now hypothetically taking this to an extreme, if all open licenses correspond to people over the age of say 50 and all 0 licenses correspond to youth say under 20, then any meaningful conclusions on the treatment cannot be separated from the hypothesis that age is in fact the driving factor. If any independents are highly correlated it becomes more difficult to determine what's driving the dependent.

Generally no, it's more a problem with how the data was sampled if true independence did exist. You can try dropping one of the offending variables in order to reduce the standard errors, but this leads to questions like which independent to drop and could lead to specification errors which is arguably more dangerous than collinearity.

Comment: Thank you for your succinct answer. In the example of age given in your response, do you think matching on the attribute - `age`, and then calculating the ATE can help increase the confidence in the result ?